# How to recursively find all possible combinations of a sequence tree?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, recursion, tree

## [Python 3.7]

---

If I have a list `A = [ [1], [2, 4], [4], [5, 6, 2], [5, 3] ]`
and I want to find all possible combinations of a single option per corresponding index, how can I *recursively* do this without the use of `for loops` (I don't want to use `for loops` because the size of other lists may be different lengths).

An example of an expected output:

```
A1 = [1, 2, 4, 5, 5]
A2 = [1, 2, 4, 5, 3]
A3 = [1, 2, 4, 6, 5]
A3 = [1, 2, 4, 6, 3]
.
.
.
A(last) = [1, 4, 4, 2, 3]
```

In my actual problem, I am trying to structure all possibilities of a sequence tree, I have found this [Tree Traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) page on Wikipedia.

---

**Some info on my actual problem**

My actual sequence structure has branches:

```
[graphical example]

           [S1]
            |          
          B3|_________ 
            |         |
           [T1]     [T7]
            |         |
            |       B4|
            |         |
           [S2]     [S3]
```

Ideal logic flow example:

```
[S1] --> [B3] --> [T1] --> [S2]
          |
          \--> [T7] --> [B4] --> [S3]
```

This results (ideally):

```
1: [ [S1], [B3], [T7], [B4], [S3] ]
2: [ [S1], [B3], [T1], [S2] ]
```

So with the given information in the context of my applied problem - what is a Pythonic manner to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do it recursively as an iterator:

```
def traverse(paths):
    if not paths: yield [];return
    for node in paths[0]:
        for subPath in traverse(paths[1:]):
            yield [node]+subPath

A = [ [1], [2, 4], [4], [5, 6, 2], [5, 3] ]

for path in traverse(A): print(path)

[1, 2, 4, 5, 5]
[1, 2, 4, 5, 3]
[1, 2, 4, 6, 5]
[1, 2, 4, 6, 3]
[1, 2, 4, 2, 5]
[1, 2, 4, 2, 3]
[1, 4, 4, 5, 5]
[1, 4, 4, 5, 3]
[1, 4, 4, 6, 5]
[1, 4, 4, 6, 3]
[1, 4, 4, 2, 5]
[1, 4, 4, 2, 3]
```

For your actual implementation you will need to replace `for node in paths[0]` and `paths[1:]` with your own method of obtaining the next available nodes.

Answer (score 2):

For the first part, maybe `itertools` can help:

```
for x in itertools.product(*A):
    print(x)
```

This prints:

```
(1, 2, 4, 5, 5)
(1, 2, 4, 5, 3)
(1, 2, 4, 6, 5)
(1, 2, 4, 6, 3)
(1, 2, 4, 2, 5)
(1, 2, 4, 2, 3)
(1, 4, 4, 5, 5)
(1, 4, 4, 5, 3)
(1, 4, 4, 6, 5)
(1, 4, 4, 6, 3)
(1, 4, 4, 2, 5)
(1, 4, 4, 2, 3)
```